# Creating files in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, file, nsdata, nsfilemanager

Which one of these 2 cases is faster in creating files?

```
Case 1:
======
NSData *data = [Some data];
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

Case 2:
=======
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath  contents:data attributes:nil];
```

Thanks
Biranchi.

Comment: The best way to find out is to test it yourself. That said, the second one (with `contents:nil`) makes more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you worrying about this... Are you going to be writing data frequently.. at like 60 FPS ?.. or 60 SPS (Saves per second) :D

Use any of the above